# Intercept all nginx locations for auth

Tags: nginx

I'm wondering how to explicitly set up auth checks in one place for every location.  Doing something like below seems like it's prone to errors (missing an entry, typos, unnecessary duplication, etc)

nginx.conf

```
location / {
 auth_request /someAuth;
 auth_request_set $someVar $someOtherVar;
 proxy_pass https://somewhere.com:1234;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
}

location /foo {
 auth_request /someAuth;
 auth_request_set $someVar $someOtherVar;
 proxy_pass https://somewhereElse.com:6578;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
}

location /bar {
 auth_request /someAuth;
 auth_request_set $someVar $someOtherVar;
 proxy_pass https://somewhereOther.com:9876;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe using a `map` directive in a way like

```
map $uri $proxy {
    ~^/foo    https://somewhereElse.com:6578;
    ~^/bar    https://somewhereOther.com:9876;
    default   https://somewhere.com:1234;
}
server {
    ...
    location / {
        auth_request /someAuth;
        auth_request_set $someVar $someOtherVar;
        proxy_pass $proxy;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

Please note that such a configuration would require a [`resolver`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver) directive.

Comment: I guess I had a bad example where all params were identical between the locations. If they were all the same the map could work, but my real world problem has different varying ones

Comment: @ekjcfn3902039 You could use several `map` blocks getting various parameters from an `$uri` nginx internal variable. Maybe if you post your real config I could suggest some more optimized solution.

Comment: I was kinda hoping for a one-liner which would act like a location interceptor before continuing to the real locations.  I guess maps are the best way to go then?

Comment: @ekjcfn3902039 I think the `map` is the best available option.